# In Semantic-UI-React, is there a way to add an x icon to a text input or dropdown that will clear the text when clicked?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I have both a text input and a dropdown that allows additions (both use the Form.xxx version). For both of these, I would like to add an x icon on the right, that when clicked, will either call a handler or will clear the input's value.

Is this possible in semantic-ui-react?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did find a solution, which I will share, but this means I can no longer have my lock icon on the left hand side, because an input can only have one icon.

What I've done is to use an [Icon](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/) element, and add an onClick handler to that, as follows:

```
<Input ...
  icon={<Icon name='delete' link onClick={this.handleDeleteClick}/>}/>
```

Comment: I modified the solution as follows: add the delete icon when the input is not empty, set the icon to user/lock/mail/etc when the input is empty.

Comment: Note: change OnClick to onClick

Comment: Support was supposed to be added for 2 icons in 1 input, but the github thread for it died.

Comment: @jarmod How does the event handler get the value of the Input? Via state?

Comment: @rjurney I didn’t provide the answer. I simply edited it later to correct a typo.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated)
To clear the field, there is no "semantic-ui-react" shortcut as far as I know.

However, you can do this manually using your component state.

Here would be an example of this:

```
class ExampleClearField extends Component {
  state = {}

  handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

  handleClear = () => this.setState({ email: ''})

  render() {
    const { email } = this.state

    return (
     <Form.Input iconPosition='left' name="email />
        <Icon name='x' link onClick={this.handleClear} />
        <input/>
     </Form.Input>

    )
  }
 }
```

** Notice the `link`, which is needed for `Icon` to accept `onClick`.

Also, dont't forget about  (you might need to change it's place depending on `iconPostion`)

Comment: morinx - thank you for your input, but I was hoping to have the delete button embedded in the input field, instead of to the right of it. Semantic-ui-react does not do a good job with these action buttons - when the focus is set, or the input is set to error, a bounding box is displayed around the input (blue or red or whatever) but the button remains gray, which just doesn't look good. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As of Semantic UI React 0.83.0, it is possible to do this with Dropdowns using `clearable`. You cannot add your own event handler to the "x" by using this. Clicking the "x" will simply clear the selected value and call onChange with the new empty value.

Example from their docs:

```
const DropdownExampleClearable = () => <Dropdown clearable options={options} selection />
```

See the example output on their docs page [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make a "x" icon appear when the "searchFilter" state is not empty.

I had to put a "margin-right" on the icon to move it away from the other icon and add the "link" prop to make it clickable:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Icon, Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

const InputWithTwoIcons = () => {
  const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState("");

  return (
    <Input
      icon={
        <>
          {searchFilter ? (
            <Icon
              name="delete"
              link
              onClick={() => {
                setSearchFilter("");
              }}
              style={{ marginRight: "1.5rem" }}
            />
          ) : null}
          <Icon name="search" color="grey" />
        </>
      }
      placeholder="Search..."
      value={searchFilter}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setSearchFilter(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default InputWithTwoIcons;
```